# Multivariable Calculus: Equation satisfied by partial derivatives implies existence of a function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

Im stuck in this question:

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\setminus\{0\} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable function whose gradient is nowhere zero and that satisfies:

$$-y\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} + x\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0$$

everywhere. Show that there is a differentiable function $F:(0,+\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ so that $f(x)=F(||x||)$.

Geometrically, if the partial derivatives of $f$ satisfies the given condition, I get that the gradient vector in any point $(x,y)$ must be orthogonal to the vector $(-y,x)$, which is the rotation of $90$ degrees counterclokwise of $(x,y)$. So, $\nabla f \,(x,y)$ will be a scalar multiple of $(x,y)$. Anyhow, this isn't helping me out to construct the desired function $F$. Any tips?

Comment: You're almost there. You've argued (how?) that the level curves of $f$ are circles centered at the origin. Therefore, $f$ is a function of $\|x\|$ alone.

Comment: @TedShifrin why circles and not for example ellipses or squares? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $r>0$, $t\in[0,2\pi)$ consider the function $g(r,t)=f(r\cos t,r\sin t)$. We have 
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}=-r\sin t\,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(r\cos t,r\sin t)+r\cos t\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(r\cos t,r\sin t)=0. 
$$
So $g(r,t)=g(r)$, and $f(r\cos t,r\sin t)=g(r)$. Now, for any $x,y$, 
$$
f(x,y)=f(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\,\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\,\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}})=g(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})=g(\|(x,y)\|). 
$$